# RewriteRule for htaccess to hide default language

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, lighttpd, multilingual

In Zend configuration defaults I have these rules:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV offline

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

When i try to add fallowing line, notfing happens:

```
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) $1 [L]
```

On result I expact to rewrite permomently http://example.com/en/something to http://example.com/something
At now I have both links worked separatly.

Edited:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV offline

RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^en/(.*) /$1 [L,R]
```

This will redirects default language urls directly to site root!
Many thanks.

There is for LigHTTPD:

```
$HTTP["url"] != "^/en/" {
    url.rewrite-once = (
        "^/.*" => "index.php?/$1",
    )
}
url.redirect = (
    "^/en/.*" => "/$1",
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's bceause `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]` is rewriting it and it never gets to the rule you added. You need to add a condition so that requests starting with `/en/` don't get rewritten to index.php:

```
# you regular stuff
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# Add this condition
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en/
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

# Now you can rewrite /en
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) $1 [L,R]
```

Edited: `example.com/en/something` gets redirected to `example.com/something`, then rewritten to `index.php`.

Comment: It seems to be workful, but it`s not work in my page. How can I check all redirects (php/http)?

Comment: Headers:
    HTTP request status: 200 (OK)
    Name Value
    Date Tue, 15 Nov 2011 09:00:19 GMT
    X-Powered-By PHP/5.2.11
    Connection Keep-Alive
    Content-Length 6377
    Pragma no-cache
    Server Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.2.11
    Content-Type text/html
    Cache-Control no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
    Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=99
    Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Comment: If you want to redirect, change the brackets to `[L,R]` in the very last rule, but note that once the browser gets redirected, the `RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]` rule will get applied. So example.com/en/something gets redirected to example.com/something, then rewritten to index.php.