# Get the language from URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have several languages on my site.

At the root I have a index.php. It's my homepage.

I want this type of url : `domain.com/fr/` or `domain.com/en/`

Witch must be the same as `domain.com/index.php?lang=fr` or `domain.com/index.php?lang=en`.

So I use this .htaccess rule:

```
# Redirect to a page (xxxxx.com/index.php?lang=fr)
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/index$  index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

But it don't work.

Could you please help me with that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|es|cn|ar)/$  index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: And if I want a default language ?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133094/rewriterule-for-htaccess-to-hide-default-language or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854820/htaccess-rule-for-language-detection